# convert hexstring to individual bytes python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, escaping, hex

Morning all,

This is probably super easy but my brain just isn't working today.

So I have a string of hex `f70307d600017010` I need to convert it to `\xf7\x03\x07\xd6\x00\x01\x70\x10`

or something to that effect, i.e escaping the string to hex.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks
Jim

Comment: What *exactly* is the result you are expecting? A `str`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions to this using regular expressions.  My favorite is this:

```
re.sub('(..)', r'\x\1', 'f70307d600017010')
```

Another could be:

```
''.join(r'\x' + x for x in re.findall('..', 'f70307d600017010'))
```

These will create a string of escaped bytes (based on the assumption that the tag "escaping" was meaning this).  If you instead want to create a string of *unescaped* bytes:

```
re.sub('(..)', lambda m: chr(int(m.group(), 16)), 'f70307d600017010')
```

EDIT:  I now prefer the answer of @juanpa-arrivillaga using the `binascii` module:  `binascii.unhexlify('f70307d600017010')`

Comment: the last one did the trick, I suspect I didn't need to actually escape the characters as I have previously thought.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the *result* of that output as a literal, i.e.:

```
>>> '\xf7\x03\x07\xd6\x00\x01\x70\x10'
'\xf7\x03\x07\xd6\x00\x01p\x10'
```

Use the `binascii` module:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> s = "f70307d600017010"
>>> binascii.unhexlify(s)
'\xf7\x03\x07\xd6\x00\x01p\x10'
```

Comment: Actually, you do not have to chunk anything using that library:  `binascii.unhexlify('f70307d600017010')` → `'\xf7\x03\x07\xd6\x00\x01p\x10'` (`p` is `\x70` so that's okay).

Comment: @Alfe yes, you are absolutely correct, how silly of me. Time to go to bed.

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means the way you should be doing it, but considering I'm bored:

```
x = "f70307d600017010"
y = "\\"
count = 1
for letter in x:
    print(count)
    if count > 2:
        y = y + "\\" + "x" + letter
        count = 1
    elif 1 == count:
        y = y + "x" + letter
    elif count % 2 == 1:
        y = y + letter + "\\"
    elif count % 2 == 0:
        y = y + letter

    count = count + 1
```